# Popping existing view controller and loading parent view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a use case where a view controller (e.g Source) loads other view controller (Login) using `performSegueWithIdentifier`

As name suggests `LoginViewController` is supposed to take user credentials, authenticate the user and load `SourceViewController` .

I created a delegate `LoginDelegate` which is implemented by `SourceViewController`. `LoginViewController` can successfully call `delegate.onSuccessfulLogin()` and `delegate.onFailedLogin()`. However, `SourceViewController` is not appearing.

Since, I didn't run any statements which give control of screen back to `SourceViewController`, I think I am running into this issue.

What is the best way, in such scenarios, to pop existing controller (LoginViewController) and give control (screen space) back to Source controller (`SourceController`)

Answer (score 0):

Call `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` or `navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` from the `LoginViewController` after calling `delegate.onSuccessfulLogin()` or `delegate.onFailedLogin()`

It will make you go back to the `SourceViewController`